# Check a condition in a string with regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string containing two comma separated numbers; something like this: `7878781,20`. I want to check the first number; if it starts with `7878`, second number should be `20`, otherwise second number after comma should has a length between 13 to 19. I want to do it with a one single line with `regex`; if it's possible! Any idea?

To clarify, I want to give some examples; these lines and similar ones should be matched:

```
7878454545,20
78858558854545,3245697412356
```

These lines and similar ones should not be matched:

```
184848,455
7878787878,45
488455784
4874854848885
```

I have tried `^(?:7878\d*,20|\d{13,19})$` and `^7878\d+,20|[\d]{13,19}$`; both match on `4874854848885` and they do not match on `87788,12345678912348`.

Comment: Seems easy enough. What have you tried?

Comment: @Biffen, I didn't know about the syntax, could you plz help

Comment: if I'm understanding you: `r'^7878\d*,(20|\d{13,19})(\D|$)'` untested. probably better to use non-capturing groups, but I'll leave that to someone's full answer

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi Find a regex book or toturial.

Comment: @cdarke, your pattern returns match object if the condition is true, but returns nothing for the else part.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi you say *otherwise it should be a number with length between 13 to 19* what you mean by *it*? do you mean all the number or one side the comma?

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: I wasn't clear what you wanted to return if it didn't match.   You have edited your question now anyway.  You have to work with us and try things yourself, not just tell us we are wrong.

Comment: @KasraAD, the second number after comma should has length between 13 and 19.

Comment: @cdarke, plz don't get me wrong. I was just explaining what I've tried. I'm so sorry if you don't feel good about my expressions.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi So i think the last answer is what you want!

Comment: @KasraAD, yes. It was completely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to be too clever here. Using something as simple as that would do the trick:

```
    m = re.match(r'^(7878\d*,20)|(\d+,\d{13,19})$', s)
    #                ^^^^^^^^^^ ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    #   if first number starts  o  two numbers, the
    #     with 7878 the second  r  second being between
    #      number should be 20     13 and 19 digits long
```

Given your test cases:

```
import re

ts = [
"7878454545,20",
"78858558854545,3245697412356",
"184848,455",
"7878787878,45",
"488455784",
"4874854848885",
]

for s in ts:
    m = re.match(r'^(7878\d*,20)|(\d+,\d{13,19})$', s)
    print(s, m is not None)
```

Producing:

```
7878454545,20 True
78858558854545,3245697412356 True
184848,455 False
7878787878,45 False
488455784 False
4874854848885 False
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will do what you want:

```
^(78)+[^(78)]+\d+,(20|\d{13,19})$
```

demo below:

https://regex101.com/r/wF3tD3/4

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi it should work now check the link for your example

Comment: I checked; it still fails in the case the first number does not meet the condition. Sylvain's answer worked. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm getting you. It has the same ouput as Sylvain in terms of regex success. Can you give me an example @ZeinabAbbasi